# SQL: ID & DTE are keys in a table, I want to get a table that has only one ID and the latest date

Tags: sql

I have a table X that has many columns. X.ID and X.START_DTE are the PKs for that table. I want to write a query that displays only one X.ID with the latest X.DTE.

What is the best way to make sure there are no duplicate X.IDs returned in my query?

Comment: Please give example data, desired results and tag with your RDBMS.

Comment: `select top 1 id from x order by dte desc`?

Comment: no that doesn't work I need it in SQL not MySQL

Comment: I am trying to understand the code the question is pretty much descriptive, 2 keys are used in a table. I need to remove duplicate IDs and get the most recent one which is sorted by date.
if you select distinct ID you'll get a smaller number say 100 vs 120 if you select all

Comment: That was sql-server syntax. If you would like help with a query, please update the question to include your specific rdbms so that everyone knows what syntax to use.

Comment: "*I need it in SQL*" - SQL is just a *query* language - it's ***not*** a DBMS product. So you will have to tell us which DBMS you use (and don't say "I use SQL"...)

Comment: sorry people for not clearing it up I use Oracle

Comment: guys please don't make any harsh comments, just help me if you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the same id can be in the table more than once with a different date and you want each id with the latest date. If that's the case then

```
select x.id,
  max(x.dte)
from x
group by x.id
```

Comment: thanks JChao, do you know how to select the other columns in the query?

Comment: You need to add them to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.